# How to make this not an infinite loop? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: java, while-loop

This is what I'm trying to do:

Write a **Java** program that reads a sequence of student records and prints the total score for each student. Each record has the student’s first and last name, followed by a sequence of test scores and a sentinel of `–1`. The sequence is terminated by the word `END`.
Here is a sample sequence:

```
Harry Morgan 94 71 86 95 -1 
Sally Lin 99 98 100 95 90 -1 
END
```

Please note: 
• Hint: you need nested loops 
• Validate the user’s entry as needed
• Don’t use arrays, you don’t have to save your values.

Here is my code so far(when I run it, it infinitely loops, my "END" won't stop the loop):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class loopshelp {

          public static void main(String[] args) {
                   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                   String name = "0";
                   while(name != "END") {
                        int sum = 0;
                        String f_name = "";
                        String l_name = "";
                        System.out.println("Enter student's first name[enter 'END' when done]");
                        f_name = input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter student's last name[enter 'END' when done]");
                        l_name = input.next();
                        name = f_name;
                        int value = 0;
                        while (value != -1) {
                             System.out.println("Enter a value[enter -1 to stop]");
                             int num = keyboard.nextInt();
                             sum = sum + num;
                             value = num;
                             }//while value != -1
                       System.out.println(f_name + " " + l_name + ": "+ (sum + 1));
                       }//while f_name != end

                  keyboard.close();
                  input.close();
                  }
            }
```

Comment: Use concat() instead of a boolean operator to compare strings.

Comment: `==` compares if two reference variables refer to the same reference or object, and this is not how you compare Strings. Use the `string1.equals(string2)` or `string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)` methods instead. So `while (!"END".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {`. Also even better to use String constants rather than inline literals.

Comment: @Taslim You probably wanted to say `equals`.

Comment: My bad.. THanks @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter

Comment: You also only need a single Scanner object. They both work the exact same

Comment: @WIZARD That's still wrong...

Comment: change your while condition to this: `while( !"END".equals(f_name) && !"END".equals(l_name))` or this to ignore case: `while( !"END".equalsIgnoreCase(f_name) && !"END".equalsIgnoreCase(l_name))`  do not compare `String` with `==`